# Restricting .DLL access

Tags: c#

Lets say I have two .dlls, Dll1 and Dll2.

DLL1 uses or makes calls into DLL2.

Is there a way I can ensure that it is DLL1 and only DLL1 who's making the calls into DLL2?

**UPDATE 1**

The reason behind this is:

I have a WinForms solution, and to keep it simple, it consists of a  view project and a controllers project (which generates a seperate .dll). After installing the application on a client machine, I realise it is possible to view the application .dlls in it's "Program Files" folder.  Somebody could potentially add a reference to the controller's .dll. I'd like to avoid this so that it's the view project and only the view project who's making the calls.

**UPDATE 2**
One of the reasons I like separating controllers into a separate project is that I could potentially have many different view projects calling into and using the same controllers.  I then would only need to maintain one controller project for all views. For instance a win forms application and a test project or even a web site using the same controller project.    But taking this approach , I would then be faced with the security problem I mention (avoiding and controlling improper use of my dll).

So I have one approach,  compiling to one .dll, by using different folders, which I believe is correct and solves my security problem, but it conditions me to only having one view.

On the other hand if I have separate projects I am faced with the security issue.

I am still dubious as to how I should go about this as I would still like to continue using different projects for the reasons I mention.

**UPDATE 3**
Any suggestions on using the StrongNameIdentityPermission permission demand?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648663.aspx   (see: Restrict Which Code Can Call Your Code)
http://blogs.msmvps.com/manoj/2004/10/20/tip-strongnameidentitypermission/  http://www.morganskinner.com/Articles/StrongNameIdentityPermission/

Thanks

Comment: Are you the author of both DLLs?

Comment: You could pass a secret key to a DLL initializer method. No other DLLs will know the key. Or use a more robust secure coding (public/private key, for example).

Comment: If DLL2 will only ever be used by DLL1, why are they not just one DLL?

Comment: If for instance my controller DLL is making database calls, retrieving records, updating, inserting, if I don't control who is actually using the DLL, potentially somebody could add a reference to it and make the calls themselves. I could avoid this by, as you suggest, organize my code in folders within the view, but I still prefer to continue having a seperate controller project so I can have many different view projects using it. I could also use "InternalsVisibleAttribute" as you suggest. I would just like to know what is a common practice when working many projects within a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make all types in DLL2 `internal` and use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) in it set to DLL1.

To ensure that this will not be subverted, you should sign DLL1 and make sure you use its public key in the attribute.

---

Alternatively, as the author of both DLLs, consider combining the projects into one - set all the public methods that exist in DLL2 to `internal`, as before, but now only DLL1 exists and they can only be accessed by it.

---

Note: All the above assumes no reflection is used.

Comment: It's a solution with several projects, each project generates a .dll. I really wouldn't like to combine all dlls in one.

Comment: @rauland - Why not? Are they deployed separately? Why have separate DLLs?

Comment: I've updated my question. Can I compile the solution so it generates only one dll? I guess I'm missing something here.

Comment: @rauland - I still don't see a reason for different projects. If you want to organize things, use folders within the project.

Comment: I have a controller's project, within the solution, which has quite a lot of functionality. I always thought it was easier to maintain, update etc If I had it in a separate project. I am starting to question my approach with what you are suggesting, so I guess instead of having several projects have separate folders.

Comment: @rauland - DLLs are units of **deployment**. Namespaces are units of logical organization. There are many reasons to not have many DLLs, however easy VS makes having them.

Comment: I think you are right, which is a bit frightening as I've been organising my solutions this way for some time now. (Many projects within one solution).

Comment: @rauland - Lots of people do, you are not alone in that. I am just pointing out that this is more of a habit than a reasoned decision in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can using Reflection to check the current callstack. Said that I probably wouldn't do it as it's costly and slow.

You can get the stacktrace this way:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

// get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the output into a single exe with [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)